# Matched case-control study for machine learning

Tags: machine-learning, case-control-study

I am currently working on a project exploring the risk factors of liver cancer using electronic health records. Originally, we planned to use a matched case-control design due to the limited number of liver cancer cases. In addition, it allows for a more valid comparison of risk factors and baseline characteristics between cases and controls.

However, we are uncertain if this type of study design is feasible for machine learning since the paired nature will not be considered in the training/test datasets splitting and the matched data may not accurately represent the general population.